# Parsing strings into seconds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have dataframe columns which contains time as the example below:

| FirstResponseTime | AverageResponseTime |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | 555 |
| 0d 00:10:08 | 151 |
| 0d 00:17:06 | NaN |

The FirstResponseTime is in "days, hours, minutes, seconds" order whereas AverageResponseTime is in seconds already.

My question is: how to parse this FirstResponseTime into seconds?

I tried

```
import datetime as datetime

df['FirstResponseTime'] = datetime.strptime(df['FirstResponseTime'], "%dd %H:%M:%S")
```

But it returns me the following message:

> AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Working with dataframes and trying to fix time is being a major issue for me, can you recommend any material?

Comment: btw. the error is caused by an inadequate import; you want to import the datetime class from the datetime module, so I think you meant to call `from datetime import datetime` (not 'as'). However in general, if using pandas, it's good to try pandas methods first, see my answer below.

Comment: @FObersteiner so I can't import the whole datetime? I meant to give datetime the short "dt" name so I could call it easier, as we do with 'numpy as np', 'pandas as pd', etc.

Comment: Of course you can, e.g. like `import datetime as dt`. But then you need to call `dt.datetime.strptime` (module -> class -> method). However, `strptime` only works for scalar inputs, not arrays as in your example (a pandas Series) - so your code will fail for another reason. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

A string like `0d 00:10:08` more likely represents a duration than a date and time. So given

```
  FirstResponseTime  AverageResponseTime
0              NaN                 555.0
1      0d 00:10:08                 151.0
2      0d 00:17:06                   NaN
```

You can parse [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html?highlight=to_timedelta) and convert to seconds as a floating point number like

```py
pd.to_timedelta(df["FirstResponseTime"], errors="coerce").dt.total_seconds()
0       NaN
1     608.0
2    1026.0
Name: FirstResponseTime, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! Question is: is there a formula to go back to the time before, or just the usual seconds/60?

Comment: @GustavoFelippedeOliveira you mean from floating point seconds to timedelta? (`pd.to_timedelta(series-with-seconds, unit="s")`)